# Msql using entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hi I am trying to connect mysql DB using Entity framework but when i am adding the ado.net entity model vs13 does not show the driver for mysql .[image]

Below are the steps that i have performed to solve the issue but it does not work for me,
1) Installed nuget packages for EF ,mysql.data &mysql.data.entity

2) Copy and paste the mysql connector dll's(mysql.data,mysql.data.entity.ef,mysql.web) in private assemblies of vs12 folder available in installed location. 
To check whether i am using right credential, I used odbc data source available in my machine and its showing the driver and allowing me a connection but same is not working for VS13

3) I have also installed the EF tool which is suggested in one of the stackover flow question and on msdn website
i have installed latest version of EF tool
Is anything missing from my end?

Comment: Does entity first or database first approaches to EF work for MySQL? (Have you tried code first which doesn't depend on any VS integration?)

Comment: database first more precisely "EF designer from database"

Comment: This is not duplicate question as i have installed the higher version of suggested tool.

Comment: Look at the answer to the linked question: there is a separate install for VS integration.

Comment: yes i  installed the latest tool for vs integration.The issue was with connector. After going in details i found that latest connectors of MySQL are developed for .net core.So this does not work for existing framework of 4.5. To solve this issue i have  downloaded the "MySql.Data.dll" of release 6.8.8 (nearly 3 release old) and it started working after updating the reference.Happy coding.....